# python difference between array(10,1) array(10,)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to load MNIST dataset into arrays.
When I use 
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)= mnist.load_data()
I get an array y_test(10000,) but I want it to be in the shape of (10000,1).
What is the difference between array(10000,1) and array(10000,)?
How can I convert the first array to the second array?

Answer (score 5):

Your first Array with shape `(10000,)` is a 1-Dimensional `np.ndarray`.
Since the `shape` attribute of numpy Arrays is a Tuple and a tuple of length 1 needs a trailing comma the shape is `(10000,)` and not `(10000)` (which would be an int). So currently your data looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5) #  >>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a.shape) #    >>> (5,)
```

What you want is an 2-Dimensional array with shape of `(10000, 1)`.
Adding a dimension of length 1 doesn't require any additional data, it is basically and "empty" dimension. To add an dimension to an existing array you can use either `np.expand_dims()` or `np.reshape()`.

Using `np.expand_dims`:

```py
import numpy as np
b = np.array(np.arange(5))  # >>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)  # >>> array([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

The function was specifically made for the purpose of adding empty dimensions to arrays. The axis keyword specifies which position the newly added dimension will occupy.

Using `np.reshape`:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5) 
X_test_reshaped = np.reshape(a, shape=[-1, 1]) # >>> array([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

The `shape=[-1, 1]` specifies how the new shape should look like after the reshape operation. The -1 itself will be replaced by the shape that 'fits the data' by numpy internally.
Reshape is a more powerful function than `expand_dims` and can be used in many different ways. You can read more on other uses of it in the numpy docs. [numpy.reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Answer (score 0):

- An array with a size of (10,1) is a 2D array containing empty columns.
- An array with a size of (10,) is a 1D array.

To convert (10,1) to (10,), you can simply collapse the columns. For example, we take the `x` array, which has `x.shape = (10,1)`. now using `x[:,0]` you can collapse the columns and `x[:,0].shape = (10,)`.

To convert (10,) to (10,1), you can add a dimension by using `np.newaxis`. So, after `import numpy as np`, assuming we are using `numpy` arrays here. Take a `y` array for example, which has `y.shape = (10,)`. Using `y[:, np.newaxis]`, you can a new array with the shape of (10,1).