# Inserting an array inside the list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an issue with numpy arrays and I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I need to create a 100x100 matrix with random int (non zero) and the last row should be the combination of all previous rows. Here is my code:

```
non_zero_m = np.random.randint(0,10,(99,100))
arr = non_zero_m.sum(axis=0)
singular_m = np.concatenate((non_zero_m, arr))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

I can't understand why python shows that arrays has different dimensions

Comment: What is `arr.shape`? Reread `np.concatenate` docs.  Also look at `np.vstack`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185055/python-difference-between-array10-1-array10 this may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that arr is a 1-dimensional array, and you are trying to concatenate it to a matrix (2-dimensional).

Just replace the second line with:

arr = non_zero_m.sum(axis=0).reshape(1, -1)

This reshapes arr to a 2-dimensonal array, such that the first axis has dimension 1 (thus making arr effectively a row vector), and the second axis has the required dimension to keep all of arr's elements (this is the meaning of -1 in this context).

Comment: Thank you so much!